# wordpress - "user-profile.min.js" and "password-strength-meter.min.js" blocked via ssl - https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, blocked

As the Title describes: I have two Wordpress JS´s that where blocked beacause it´s not loading from `https`. But Why?

I´m not sure if thats right but this is already set: `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`

My Server try to load it from:

`http://examples.tld/wordpress/wp-admin/user-profile-min.js`

But it has to be from https:

`https://examples.tld/wordpress/wp-admin/user-profile-min.js`

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How does the code for including those JS files look like? Does the problem occur in your custom theme page or inside wp-admin?

Comment: i thought it´s a part of wordpress not of the theme? But it´s blocking on any site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try removing http:

```
//examples.tld/wordpress/wp-admin/user-profile-min.js
```

Worked for me.